# Hash sum mismatch error during system update

Tags: updates

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
[sudo] password for kmkd:            
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                  
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [697 kB]                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [565 kB]                                  
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [282 kB]                          
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.7 kB]                            
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [129 kB]                             
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [342 kB]                           
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                            
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                            
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                                              
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                                              
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                                              
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                            
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                            
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [980 kB]                                                  
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                     
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:980004 [weak]
   - SHA256:2595356e5b75eec44b222f9fd5a03b03e4c8b54dfaf9c23fbaf30524dba903ff
   - SHA1:262430e9ffe83545e1c76a64c604995572aee9b5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e86ead6cfed7dff1f8c9a8b1ba47db93 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:7af2952db640563c2cae82a72868b0ade918b30636b13c3d793766e6190ca696
   - SHA1:afe01dadae607eee0a98339d550f6308b5cdeb17 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:83b9d0465f13bceb45e21a7f02974a3f [weak]
   - Filesize:980004 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 07:06:34 +0000
  Release file created at: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 07:43:49 +0000
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Hit:19 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease                                                            
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                               
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Fetched 1,157 kB in 1s (830 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/2595356e5b75eec44b222f9fd5a03b03e4c8b54dfaf9c23fbaf30524dba903ff  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:980004 [weak]
    - SHA256:2595356e5b75eec44b222f9fd5a03b03e4c8b54dfaf9c23fbaf30524dba903ff
    - SHA1:262430e9ffe83545e1c76a64c604995572aee9b5 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e86ead6cfed7dff1f8c9a8b1ba47db93 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:7af2952db640563c2cae82a72868b0ade918b30636b13c3d793766e6190ca696
    - SHA1:afe01dadae607eee0a98339d550f6308b5cdeb17 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:83b9d0465f13bceb45e21a7f02974a3f [weak]
    - Filesize:980004 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 07:06:34 +0000
   Release file created at: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 07:43:49 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/), hash sum mismatch errors are usually more typical for clients behind proxy caches. To solve the issue, remove all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```